# Socket.io GET/POST 404

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, sockets

I was searching for a similiar issue, but I still can't fix this problem. I'm working on a chat app in ReactJs, Node/Express, Mongoose and Socket.io. Everything works, db is working, server is running, so now I want to add socket. I'm trying to connect client side with server, but I get error (about every 2/3sec) POST/GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N5PeKkf 404 (Not Found).

React:

```
  const host = 'http:localhost:5000/api/rooms'
  const [endpoint, setEndpoint] = useState('')

  const {width,mobileWidth} = props;

  useEffect(()=>{
    setEndpoint(`${host}${props.location.pathname}`);
    socket = io(endpoint);
    const roomId = props.location.pathname.slice(1,props.location.pathname.length);

    socket.emit('join', {roomId})

  },[endpoint])
```

Node:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const socketIo = require("socket.io");
const http = require("http");

const HttpError = require('./models/http-error');
const roomsRouter = require('./routes/rooms-routes');
const usersRouter = require('./routes/users-routes');

const app = express();

mongoose
   .connect(
      `mongodb+srv://${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASSWORD}@cluster0-lnoai.mongodb.net/${process.env.DB_NAME}?retryWrites=true&w=majority`
   )
   .then(() => {
      app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);
   })
   .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
   });


const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIo(server);

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
   res.setHeader(
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
      'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
   );
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE');

   next();
});

io.on('connection',(socket)=>{
   console.log('connected');
})


app.use('/api/rooms', roomsRouter);
app.use('/api/users', usersRouter);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
   throw new HttpError('Route not found.', 404);
});

app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
   if (res.headerSent) {
      return next(error);
   }

   res.status(error.code || 500).json({
      message: error.message || 'An uknown error occurres!',
      errorCode: error.code || 500
   });
});
```

Comment: You've started http listener on port `5000` but Your frontend tries to connect using `:3000` so fix socket io connection on clientside to use `5000` for socket io too or put http server like `nginx` in front of Your react and express app.

Comment: Could you explain me how to do it?

Comment: read socket io manual about customizing connection url or serve react app from express app.

Comment: io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:5000');

Comment: it doesnt work for me ; /

Comment: `npm i —save cors` in backend app, `app.use(require('cors')());` and enable developer mode in chrome

Comment: Take Your time and watch tutorials in YouTube: `reactjs socket.io tutorial` especially this one: https://youtu.be/ZwFA3YMfkoc

Comment: I started with this tutorial, but he doesn't use mongoose. I put io into mongoose, and now I' m connected console.log('connected') worked, but still I can't emit anything from React.
POST http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N5QJrcg 404 (Not Found)

I didn't change my localhost and I have exactly like that guy from tutorial